# Find Pandas column largest/smallest values where dates don't overlap

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,1,2,3,4,5])
df['XYZ'] = [2, 8, 6, 5, 9, 10]
df['Date2'] = ["2005-01-06", "2005-01-07", "2005-01-08", "1994-06-08", "1999-06-15", "2005-01-09"]
df['Date1'] = ["2005-01-02", "2005-01-03", "2005-01-04", "1994-06-04", "1999-06-12", "2005-01-05"]
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'])
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'])
```

I need to follow the 2 largest values of XYZ with dates that do not overlap. The expected output would be:

```
XYZ   Date1       Date2
10    2005-01-05  2005-01-09
9     1999-06-12  1999-06-15
5     1994-06-04  1994-06-08
```

I tried to sort by "XYZ":

```
df.sort_values(by="XYZ", ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

And then compare dates:

```
df['overlap'] = (df['Date1] <= df['Date2'].shift()) & (df['Date2'] >= df['Date1'].shift())
```

And then drop any `True` values in df['overlap'] and take the `nlargest()` values, however that results in cases that do overlap.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix your reproducible example please? the code you provided to build the dataframe does not work unfortunately. There's an ```=``` instead of ```-```, and you give 6 indexes but 5 column values

Comment: my apologies, you are right. It should work now

Comment: @dsugasa your Dates columns are inverted, either in the input or the output

Comment: you are right. The dates input and output should be consistent now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat involved but hopefully will work for you. We introduce a `mask` indexed by every date between the min and the max date in your df, where we mark each date as 'used' if it appears in the range, and then use that to reject overlapping rows

First we get the min and the max date (while also sorting the original df by 'XYZ')

```
df1 = df.sort_values('XYZ', ascending = False)
dmin, dmax = df1[['Date1', 'Date2']].unstack().agg([min,max])
```

then we create a mask populated with 0s initially

```
mask = pd.Series(index = pd.date_range(dmin,dmax), data = 0)
```

Then we iterate over rows marking those we want in the 'include' column

```
for idx,row in df1.iterrows():
    if sum(mask[row['Date1']:row['Date2']]) > 0:
        df1.loc[idx, 'include'] = False
        continue
    mask[row['Date1']:row['Date2']] = 1
    df1.loc[idx, 'include'] = True
```

finally filter on 'include'

```
df1[df1['include']].drop(columns = 'include')
```

output

```
    XYZ Date1       Date2
5   10  2005-01-05  2005-01-09
4   9   1999-06-12  1999-06-15
3   5   1994-06-04  1994-06-08
```

Comment: thank you. I am glad I asked, I wouldn't have come up with that solution!